# Postgresql criteria for record to text conversion

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Working on two servers, I found differences in the way Postgresql compose a record and converts it to text. I can't find which is the configuration involved in this difference.

As a test, I run the following query:

```
select ('Innovatività','CGC')::text, row('Innovatività','CGC');
```

On first server I got:

```
(Innovatività,CGC)  (Innovatività,CGC)
```

On the second server I got:

```
("Innovatività",CGC)    ("Innovatività",CGC)
```

On a third server check I got the same result as the second one.

Comparing the results, the second server enclose the string `Innovatività` with double quotes, the first server doesn't do it.

About the servers:

- First (without double quotes):

  - version 9.4.14
  - lc_collate = en_US.UTF-8
- Second (double quotes):

  - version 9.4.8
  - lc_collate = Italian_Italy.1252
- Third (double quotes):

  - version 9.6.6
  - lc_collate = Italian_Italy.1252

Do you know why?

I know that `lc_collate` is different between the servers, but I don't know I can check if the problem is this (and in case I don't know how to fix it). I have tried the command `set lc_collate = en_US.UTF-8` but the `lc_collate` can't be changed with `set` command.

Comment: Always the same client. Show lc_collate changes: `en_US.UTF-8` on the first server and `Italian_Italy.1252` (I update the question). How can I test it?